# Don't understand how Django's CSRF protection works

Tags: javascript, django, csrf, django-csrf

Reading this [section of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) they recommend setting a csrftoken in a cookie and then having the client-side framework put this in a header which will be validated on a server-side request.  However, doesn't having the token in a cookie defeat the purpose because the cookies are sent on every user's request?

Or is the "security" here that Django checks for that value in a header rather than checking the cookie value itself?

I do understand why this works for synchronous submissions, but in that case the csrftoken is written directly to the page rather than stored in a cookie, which seems more secure.

From the [OWASP page on reviewing code for CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_code_for_Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_issues):

> Checking if the request has a valid session cookie is not enough, we
>   need check if a unique identifier is sent with every HTTP request sent
>   to the application. CSRF requests WON'T have this valid unique
>   identifier. The reason CSRF requests won't have this unique request
>   identifier is the unique ID is rendered as a hidden field on the page
>   and is appended to the HTTP request once a link/button press is
>   selected. The attacker will have no knowledge of this unique ID, as it
>   is random and rendered dynamically per link, per page.

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood a few things.

The token is always in a cookie; the code you link to is for getting it *out* of the cookie in your JS so that you can send it back.

And the point is, as your quote shows, that an attacker trying to post from a page that is not on the site will not have that cookie, so won't be able to inject the right value into the form or the header.

Comment: "The token is always in a cookie" is not correct. Also normal forms, which are not send trough ajax, must contains csrf token in hidden input field.

Comment: My understanding from the OWASP page is that cookies aren't a good way to handle this because they will be automatically set for the domain.  So if I get you to click on www.socialnetwork.com/myAccount/delete, your cookies are going to be sent, just like they are sent for every www.socialnetwork.com request.

Are you saying the act of checking for the csrftoken in a header instead of the cookie what makes this a viable approach?

Comment: @AntonBessonov CSRF protection works by comparing the cookie against the header/hidden input. A potential attacker can't get the correct value from the cookie without exploiting other vulnerabilities (such as XSS), so in case of an attack, the CSRF token in the header/hidden input won't have the same value as the cookie. When these values don't match, the request is rejected. However, for this to work the token must always be set in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with django csrf protection, but I think it's work like other csrf protections in other frameworks.

The trick is, send csrf token to the client through cookie and client use header to send it back to the server. Server ignore cookie, but not header. How it prevents csrf attack? For example, attacker can bind `<img src="yourwebsite.com/action/destroy/data">` (or sends post request through javascript). Your browser sends csrf cookie (and also session cookie) with it. Because header is missing - attack is prevented.

Same with forms. I think both, headers and forms are equal secure.

But in both cases you are lost, if you have a xss vulnerability.

EDIT: as Daniel points out, it's make sense to remove csrf cookie. But this is not for security reason.

Comment: The cookie is not ignored, it is _essential_ in Django's CSRF protection. Daniel points out it makes sense to _read_ the cookie, not to _remove_ the cookie. An attacker can trivially add a header or hidden input field with some random CSRF token, so checking for just that is not enough. To ensure protection, the header/hidden input value must be the same as the cookie's value. An attacker won't be able to get the value of the cookie, so a forged request will have different values in the cookie and header/hidden input, and is rejected. A legitimate request will have matching values.